# iSCSI multipath settings on CentOS6.5

Tags: centos, iscsi

All,

I want to know is it possible to use only one network card to configure iSCSI multipath for the backend iSCSI storage? E.g, I have a NIC of eth0 with IP address of 192.168.10.100,then I create a virtual NIC of eth0:1 with IP address of 192.168.11.100. The two IPs are corresponding to the ip addresses of the two controllers of the iSCSI storage. Or should one must use two separate physical NICs for iSCSI multipath? I tried the above settings but found only one path is available for any volumes attached to the server. I can ping both IPs of the controllers(192.168.10.10 and 192.168.11.10) without problem.

Cheers,
  Doan

Answer (score 0):

To use one network card for multipathing, you need the two NICs on that card to be used, with each one on a different subnet, i.e. using a different switch. It's still not great to have just one NIC card to do this, since that's a single point of failure. For maximum robustness, each path should be independent of the other as much as possible.

So I believe the answer is that it is possible but not recommended.